# Memory leaks in class

Tags: c++

I have problem with memory leaks. Tested it in program called "Deleaker".
If I comment out content of destructor it's working with these memory leaks correctly.
Thank you for any help.

Inventory.h

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H

#include "Item.h"

class InventoryOfItems {
public:
    InventoryOfItems(int c = 10);
    ~InventoryOfItems();

    bool Add(Item* newItem);
    Item* Remove(int itemIndex);
    int Size() const;
    int Items() const;
    int Weapons() const;
    int Potions() const;
    Item::item_t GetItemType(int invIndex) const;

    void DisplayWeapons();
    void DisplayPotions();
    void DisplayInfo();
private:
    Item** items;
    int itemCount;
    int capacity;
};

#endif  /* INVENTORY_H */
```

Inventory.cpp

```
#include "Inventory.h"
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "Potion.h"

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw;
using std::setiosflags;
using std::ios;

#include <string>

InventoryOfItems::InventoryOfItems(int cap) {
    itemCount = 0;
    capacity = cap;
    items = new Item*[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        items[i] = 0;
    }
}

InventoryOfItems::~InventoryOfItems() {

    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        delete items[i];
    }

    delete [] items;
}

bool InventoryOfItems::Add(Item* newItem) {
    if (newItem == 0)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        if (items[i] == 0) { // empty
            switch (newItem->GetType()) { 

                case Item::Weapon:
                {

                    Weapon* originalWeapon = (Weapon*) newItem;
                    Weapon* newWeapon = new Weapon(originalWeapon);

                    items[i] = newWeapon;
                    itemCount++;
                    break;
                }
                case Item::Potion:
                {
                    Potion* originalPotion = (Potion*) newItem;
                    Potion* newPotion = new Potion(originalPotion);
                    items[i] = newPotion;
                    itemCount++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}

Item* InventoryOfItems::Remove(int itemIndex) {
    if (items[itemIndex - 1] == 0)
        return 0;
    else {
        Item* itemToReturn;
        itemToReturn = items[itemIndex - 1];
        items[itemIndex - 1] = 0;
        itemCount--;
        return itemToReturn;
    }
}

int InventoryOfItems::Size() const {
    return capacity;
}

int InventoryOfItems::Items() const {
    return itemCount;
}

int InventoryOfItems::Weapons() const {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        if (items[i] != 0)
            if (items[i]->GetType() == Item::Weapon)
                count++;

    return count;
}

int InventoryOfItems::Potions() const {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        if (items[i] != 0)
            if (items[i]->GetType() == Item::Potion)
                count++;

    return count;
}

Item::item_t InventoryOfItems::GetItemType(int invIndex) const {
    if (items[invIndex - 1] == 0)
        return Item::Undefined;
    else
        return items[invIndex - 1]->GetType();
}

void InventoryOfItems::DisplayWeapons() {
    cout << "  WEAPONS" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        if (items[i] != NULL)
            if (items[i]->GetType() == Item::Weapon) {
                cout << "    " << setiosflags(ios::right) << setw(2) << i + 1 << ": ";
                items[i]->DisplayInfo();
                cout << endl;
            }
}

void InventoryOfItems::DisplayPotions() {
    cout << "  POTIONS" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        if (items[i] != NULL)
            if (items[i]->GetType() == Item::Potion) { 
                cout << "    " << setiosflags(ios::right) << setw(2) << i + 1 << ": ";
                items[i]->DisplayInfo();
                cout << endl;
            }
}

void InventoryOfItems::DisplayInfo() {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "  ----------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "  Inventory (carrying " << itemCount << " of " << capacity << " items)" << endl;
    cout << "  ----------------------------------" << endl;

    DisplayWeapons();
    DisplayPotions();
}
```

Calling Remove:

```
void Hero::equip()
{
    int item = 0;

    if(inv.Items() == 0)
    {
        cout << "Your inventory is empty!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        inv.DisplayWeapons();
        cout << "Choose a weapon: " << endl;
        cin >> item;

        if(weapon != NULL)
        {
            inv.Add(weapon);
        }

        Weapon *selected = (Weapon*) inv.Remove(item);
        weapon = new Weapon(selected);
        delete selected;
    }
}
```

weapon is pointer to weapon (hand of hero)

Comment: Look at Rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: so, is there a problem you are having if you don't comment the destructor?

Comment: You should probably use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>`.

Comment: @Mike ye... error for object 0x7f87e3c031d0: pointer being freed was not allocated

Comment: You should probably reduce your code to a [mcve]. Doing that will probably get you your answer. Having said that, double-check that you are calling `delete` on the objects returned by `Remove`.

Comment: @KeithM I'm new in coding in C++.. actually learning from books.. I see it know but have no idea how to fix it..

Comment: Getting all the details right with dynamically allocated memory and arrays can complicated. That's why you should use `std::vector`, it takes care of the tricky stuff for you.

Comment: @Barmar I will google it, I didn't learn it yet :/

Comment: @Barmar could you help me please?
I actually included header <vector>
and vector<Item*> items(capacity);
Don't know what more to do :/

Comment: @JacobLeet Here's a tutorial for `std::vector` etc.: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20930/The-complete-guide-to-STL-Part-Vector

Comment: @JacobLeet Sorry, I'm not going to completely rewrite your program for you.

Comment: Also your problem is not Verifiable unless you post the code calling `Remove`, so you should add that code or your question may be closed.

Comment: @KeithM Already added..

Comment: Your Remove method can perform an out-of-bounds memory access when itemIndex is outside the range of the capacity (i.e. itemIndex = 0 or itemIndex = capacity). Your equip method does not explicitly prevent item not being out-of-range since you ask for user input. Are you sure you're testing the equip method with 'valid' indexes/keys?

Comment: Stop using pointers; you will suddenly find you have much fewer trouble with memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not `delete`-ing `weapon` before overwriting it. Note the added line:

```
    inv.DisplayWeapons();
    cout << "Choose a weapon: " << endl;
    cin >> item;

    if(weapon != NULL)
    {
        inv.Add(weapon);
        delete weapon;  // Added
    }

    Weapon *selected = (Weapon*) inv.Remove(item);
    weapon = new Weapon(selected); // `weapon` would be overwritten here
    delete selected;
```

Having said that, I also recommend using `std::vector` instead of all these pointers, as we said in the question comments, because messing up memory management is easy.

Comment: I have delete weapon in destructor of class Hero

Comment: That would only be called if `Hero` were being destructed. It is not being destructed from within `Hero::equip()`. Destructors are called when an object is deleted or goes out of scope. You aren't deleting your `Hero` object, nor would it go out of scope within its own function.

Comment: there is still problem with that inventory destructor.. when i comment it its working.. when not its giving me error for object.. jesus why

and yeah I will use vector just.. just trying to rewrite it with vector ... :/

Comment: @JacobLeet You must have another leak somewhere else besides the code you posted, then. But you definitely need this `delete`. Are you sure you're not calling `Remove` anywhere else?

Comment: Destructor is called 2 times..
1) When I choose hero type.. in hero constructor is 
 Weapon *l = new Weapon("Sword", 3, 1, 2);
 inv.Add(l);
 delete l;
2) When programs exit.. so I think in first call I'm deleting items which I'm using then in program.. that's problem

Comment: @JacobLeet That doesn't necessarily mean very much about the `equip()`. Actually, you could also be not deleting the items that are passed to `Add`. Is there any reason you make copies of all the items instead of just saving off the pointer? If destructor is getting called twice, make sure you're NOT calling it explicitly anywhere. Destructors are called automatically.

Comment: look up I found the problem I think

Comment: Did you miss the last part of my comment? "If destructor is getting called twice, make sure you're NOT calling it explicitly anywhere. Destructors are called automatically."

Comment: I found problem it's because I'm calling default Hero constructor and then constructor with parameters.. when I call constructor with parametres it's giving me error

Comment: @JacobLeet that constructor looks fine, since your `Add` function makes a copy of the item. I also see no reason why that would call the `InventoryOfItems` destructor.

Comment: @JacobLeet You also cannot explicitly call constructors from within other constructors. (It just creates a new blank object and then immediately deletes it.) If you need to do this, make an `Initialize` function instead, which gets called from both versions of the constructor. Post your code if you don't get it and then ping me with a comment.

Comment: I will use just default constructor of hero and when I choose type of hero I will use set functions to set stats it will be good. Cuz it's working with default constructor of hero without problems now :)

Comment: @JacobLeet You should still learn why what you did is wrong, or you'll make the same mistake again later...

Comment: @JacobLeet You can also click the check mark next to an answer to accept the answer as having solved the problem.